# Reading - Writing XML dynamicly in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, save

I've following problem:

I am reading from a existing xml-file like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    //Deks.
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( "FILE" ) or die (" Couldnt load. ");
    foreach ($xml->children() as $one){
        foreach ($one->children() as $two ){
            foreach($two->children() as $three ){
                $array = array();
                foreach ($three as $key => $value ){
                    $array[ ( string ) $key ] = ( string )$value;
                    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So I get my needed output.

My XML looks like this:

```
<overx>
    <overy>
        <katx>
            <katy>
                <rnd>true</rndm>
            </katy>
            <rely>
                <lwm>true</lwm>
            </rely>
        </katx>
    </overy>
</overy>
```

The xml-file is shortened heavily. Most of children have different names also their children has.

Now I want to create a html form which reads the xml form dynamically.
That's the way I am doing it:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $form_fields  = null;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( "FILE" ) or die (" Couldnt load. ");
    foreach ( $xml->children() as $one){
        foreach ( $one->children() as $two ){
            foreach( $two->children() as $three ){
                $array = array();
                foreach ( $three as $field ){
                    $form_fields .= '<div>';
                    $form_fields .=  '<label>' . ucfirst($field->getName()) . ' </label>';
                    if ($field->getName() == "active" ){
                        $form_fields .=  '<input type="checkbox" value="true"'.$field->getName() . '" />';
                    }
                    else{
                        $form_fields .=  '<input type="text" name="'.$field->getName() . '" />';
                    }
                    $form_fields .= '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But now I have the following problem:
I want to save the form as .xml which have exactly the same structure as the XML it's loaded from. Actually, I am saving poorly via javascript and right now it's only saving key->value but not the structure or anything else and I really don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could reverse the BadgerFish translation (which is XML-to-JSON) by setting up the form names appropriately. Mind that the form control names do not necessarily look intuitive.